# react-datepicker version 4.1.1. year drop down header arrow not showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

Even same issue we can see in documentation [react-datepicker year dropdown](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-year-dropdown). I know it's version specific issue as it's working fine in lower version. Any solution for this version?

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      showYearDropdown
      dateFormatCalendar="MMMM"
      yearDropdownItemNumber={15}
      scrollableYearDropdown
    />
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Year drop down have `react-datepicker__year-dropdown` class in `css`. So we can create a custom style and select the year dropdown based on this class and add the arrow icon. Custom styles will be:

```
.react-datepicker__year-dropdown .react-datepicker__year-option:first-child::before {
  content: "\25B2";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 45%;
  margin: auto;
}

.react-datepicker__year-dropdown::after {
  content: "\25BC";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15%;
}
```

Assume `DatePicker` component's code is same as bellow:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

export default function App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      showYearDropdown
      dateFormatCalendar="MMMM"
      yearDropdownItemNumber={15}
      scrollableYearDropdown
    />
  );
}
```

We add our styles in `styles.css`.

[image: Edit goofy-bhaskara-8llxq]